# Question on the definition of a locally presentable category

Tags: category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

According to [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category), a category $C$ is called *locally presentable* if it is accessible and has all small colimits.

Moreover, one [can show](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category#AsLocalizationsOfPresheafCategories), that this conditions are equivalent to the condition of $C$ being a reflective subcategory of some presheaf-category $PSh(K)$  for a small category $K$ such that the inclusion $i\colon C\hookrightarrow PSh(K)$ is an [accessible functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/accessible+functor).

I once saw the definition of $C$ being *locally presentable* if $C$ is just a reflective subcategory of some presheaf-category $PSh(L)$?

> Are this conditions equivalent? If yes, do I have to change the category $K$ in order to get the last 'definition' (i.e. is the second definition just redundant and the inclusion is automatically accessible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to expect to be able to get accessibility for free. On the other hand, I know of no explicit counterexamples – and indeed, if you assume [Vopěnka's principle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vop%C4%9Bnka%27s+principle), then you can show that every reflective subcategory of a locally presentable category is automatically a locally presentable category.

Comment: Thank you, Zhen Lin. But when Vopěnka's principle is used, the small category $K$ changes, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Dear Zhen Lin, please let me clarify if I have understood your answer correctly: It is clear that a reflective subcategory $C$ of a presheaf-category $PSh(L)$ has all small colimits (and all small limits) but it is according to your answer **not** always the case that such a $C$ is an accessible category, right? On the other hand I can't see why I cannot just use the reflected generators of $PSh(L)$ as generators for $C$. Aren't these always generators for $C$? Thank you.

Comment: They are generators but they are not necessarily presentable.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand it correctly, that if $C$ is a topos (e.g. defined as  a reflective subcategory $i\colon C\to PSh(K)$ with a left-exact reflector), then it is true that $C$ is locally presentable but probably with another inclusion $j\colon C\to PSh(K)$ and another $K$?

Comment: You do not need to change $K$. The inclusion is automatically accessible in that case.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference for that or is it ''obvious''?

Comment: Given a fully faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Psh} (\mathcal{K})$ with a left adjoint, if $\mathcal{C}$ is accessible, then the functor is also accessible. This is an easy exercise.